# Chrome use-mobile-user-agent not working

Tags: c++, google-chrome, selenium, user-agent, chromium

## Chrome *use-mobile-user-agent* not working

Running chrome from command line with flag `--use-mobile-user-agent` does not open the browser in mobile context (user-agent).

```
chrome --use-mobile-user-agent= true
```

**Note:**

> passing user-agent option does work, **but** i feel its not the right way of doing things as chrome offers you this flag to boot in mobile context.

```
--user-agent= Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X; ar) AppleWebKit/534.46.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/19.0.1084.60 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3
```

## Chromium source code

reading some of the [chromium source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/public/common/content_switches.cc?sq=package:chromium&type=cs&rcl=1474182991&l=866), i see the following:

#### content_switches.cc

define `kUseMobileUserAgent` from `"use-mobile-user-agent"` flag:
Set when Chromium should use a mobile user agent.

```
const char kUseMobileUserAgent[] = "use-mobile-user-agent";
```

#### shell_content_client.cc

add "Mobile" to product if our variable switch is true/set.

```
std::string GetShellUserAgent() {
  std::string product = "Chrome/" CONTENT_SHELL_VERSION;
  base::CommandLine* command_line = base::CommandLine::ForCurrentProcess();
  if (command_line->HasSwitch(switches::kUseMobileUserAgent))
    product += " Mobile";
  return BuildUserAgentFromProduct(product);
}
```

## Extra detail *(running from selenium)*

As an extra detail, i run chrome in using selenium and pass the configurations:

```
 ...

 "browserName": "chrome",
 "chromeOptions": {
     "args": [
         "--user-agent= Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X; ar) AppleWebKit/534.46.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/19.0.1084.60 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3",
         "--window-size=320,640",
         "--disable-popup-blocking",
         "--incognito",
         "--test-type"
     ]
 },

 ...
```

Comment: Do you need this for chrome driver? And I think you can't apply flags to chrome, you would probably had to use Chromium.

Comment: I can't prove it for sure - which is why I am commenting instead of answering. But it appears that flag is used for android command line only. That is how it is being unit tested. https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/chrome_content_client_unittest.cc?q=kUseMobileUserAgent&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=81

Comment: @Scott other arguments work normally, such as `window-size` or `disable-popup-blocking` so i dont believe thats it, maybe its a chrome bug, or it adds "Mobile" to `user-agent` which is useless, not a certain real mobile agent (i'm unable to check the user agent due to other constraints)

Comment: It's probably a bug. Have you already filed a bug report on the Chromium project site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string is built to "Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Mobile" in `GetShellUserAgent`, then in `BuildUserAgentFromProduct`, product is not used, and passed on to `BuildUserAgentFromOSAndProduct`, which is supposed to format a string as such;

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (%s) AppleWebKit/%d.%d (KHTML, like Gecko) %s Safari/%d.%d"
```

The product string is inserted into token four, where the fourth replacement token is before "Safari". Therefore "Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Mobile" should be placed there.

With and without the flag, my user agent is the same.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
```

So what does this mean, is it broken? Quite possibly.

In `src/extensions/shell/common/shell_content_client.cc`, `BuildUserAgentFromProduct("Chrome/" PRODUCT_VERSION)` is called in `ShellContentClient::GetUserAgent`. That just circumvents the call to `GetShellUserAgent`.

Well. There goes the mobile user agent flag. There's other places it's possible for the product to be replaced, but that's the one that sticks out as the culprit.